# azure continuous deployment fail

Tags: asp.net, azure, dnx

ll of the sudden, Azure continuous deployment constantly fails. Can't get  the reason. Here is deployment log, where fail happens.

```
    Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\project.json...
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.platforms/index.json
WARNING: Detected package downgrade: System.Xml.XmlSerializer from 4.0.10-beta-23109 to 4.0.0-beta-23109 
 repository (>= 1.0.0) -> WindowsAzure.Storage (>= 6.2.2-preview) -> System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml (>= 4.0.10-beta-23109) -> System.Private.DataContractSerialization (>= 4.0.0-beta-23109) -> System.Xml.XmlSerializer (>= 4.0.10-beta-23109) 
 repository (>= 1.0.0) -> WindowsAzure.Storage (>= 6.2.2-preview) -> System.Xml.XmlSerializer (>= 4.0.0-beta-23109)
Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 supports:
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net45+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7)
Package Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.4 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.4 supports:
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile328)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
  - sl4 (Silverlight,Version=v4.0)
Package Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.4 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.4 supports:
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
  - sl4 (Silverlight,Version=v4.0)
Package System.Spatial 5.6.4 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package System.Spatial 5.6.4 supports:
```

Tried it with the newest version of the code, with previously successfully deployed versions, with new app, with new app and different app.

Comment: I am literally seeing this same exact thing. Started happening yesterday for me.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd say they're using the new NuGet, which probably means you need to update your project.json file to add imports statements to add compatibility between PCLs and DNX.

Comment: Do you have any links or resources? I'm running into the same issue - works locally but not on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

To workaround this issue, you can specify a specific version of the `System.Xml.XmlSerializer` package that works with your project.

Here is a description of how to solve it specific to RC2. Not sure which version would be for RC1.

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1469#issuecomment-220251320

Comment: do you believe this warning causes following error with Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 is not compatible with dnxcore50 ?

Comment: You should also include import "dnxcore50" on dependencies. If you visit slack you can get guidance faster/easier

Comment: Hey. As far as I understand, this message relates to RC2. So, the question is.. Did Azure begin RC2 w/o any notice? Can I opt out back to rc1?